# Create new field type in sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

How can i create the new field type in sonata admin bundle that i can use in configureFormFields (FormMapper). The challenge is to make autocompete with google api (geolocation).

P.S. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom form field type in symfony2 like explained here (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) and then you can use it in SonataAdminBundle like this:

```
 $formMapper->add('field_name', 'field_custom_type');
```